# Mistaken dist-upgrade, is this bad?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, apt

I was looking for `Update Manager` on Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition and couldn't find it, so in Terminal I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got a message saying some packages were "held back" and searching online gave me the suggestion to do:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

So I did that and it updated my kernel and now `uname -a` says I have `2.6.35-23-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP`.  My system is still working normally, but I'm now second-guessing if I did the right thing.  Was this kernel update meant for the next version of Ubuntu?  Should I try to back it out?

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it nor worry about it.

Comment: Incidentally, where is `Update Manager`?  Since upgrading to 10.10 (Netbook) I can't find it

Comment: goto dash then in search type update manager.

Answer (score 11):

`dist-upgrade` has some advanced package dependency resolution that is used (possibly needed) when a package changes it's major version.

Updates, for example, will always keep your version of OpenOffice 1.x up to date, but as soon as the distribution switches to OpenOffice 2.x, a dist-upgrade will be needed to resolve some more complicated issues.

So: **You didn't do anything wrong**. If you want, you can always do `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. It happens automatically if needed (via Update Manager), but you may invoke it manually to your hearts content.

Safe for errors in the repository `apt` is pretty much bullet proof these days. :)

Answer (score 4):

The only difference between *apt-get upgrade* and *apt-get dist-upgrade* is that *dist-upgrade* will install new packages or remove installed packages if that is necessary to fulfil package dependencies, while *upgrade* will hold back packages whose dependencies can't be fulfilled by just upgrading.

So if there are some hold back packages usually *apt-get dist-upgrade* is The *Right Thing To Do*.

But it's a good idea to first have a look on what it wants to do, especially if you are using unofficial packages sources like PPAs or *apt-get dist-upgrade* wants to remove packages.